# Pick an item from a list based on a condition

Tags: netlogo

I have an agent's list made up by elements from its neighbours' lists. I would need to pick an item from it based on a parameter: the higher the parameter h is, the more probable is to pick that item.

To pick the item I tried with: `print one-of list`, where list contains all the items collected from a neighbour (`set list lput item list`).

However, I do not know how to add the condition about the parameter. 
I tried with `max (list item)`, but this does not consider the value of the parameter h (it can take values from 1 to 10).

Could you please suggest me how to consider it? 
Many thanks

Comment: Add some tags about your language lisp? And tools

Comment: Hi Simson. I already added it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rnd extension does exactly what you need. Put `extensions [rnd]` at the top of your code. Then use `rnd:weighted-one-of-list` to do the selection. Here is a complete program that demonstrates. Put it in an empty NetLogo model and then run the testme procedure several times.

```
extensions [rnd]
to testme
  let mylist [1 3 5]
  repeat 10
  [ type rnd:weighted-one-of-list mylist [ [ii] -> ii ]
    type " "
  ]
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much, JenB. I have never used the extensions before so I did not know about that.

Comment: Hi JenB, is it correct to use the extension in the following way, if I want to pick an item from a list? `rnd:weighted-one-of-list mylist [ [ii] -> ii ] 
set mylist lput old_item mylist print "Old item" ; add items to the list` (I already wrote a new post, but unfortunately no one seems to know how to help regarding that. Probably you will be able to answer the question as it related to what you suggested me in this post)

Comment: your other question is too confused to answer. Can you just ask one question with an example of input and expected output?